# WRONGTYPE Operation with Redisson Live Objects

Tags: java, redis, redisson

I've upgraded my `Redisson` library to `3.13.2`(from `3.11.1`) and since then I keep getting `WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value` as soon as I perform `liveObjectService.persist(reporterObject)`.

I have the following class:

```
@Getter
@ToString
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@REntity
public class ReporterObject {
    @RId
    private long id;
    private long rId;
    @RIndex
    @Setter
    private long sId;
    @Setter
    private boolean ac;
    @RIndex
    @Setter
    private Long parId;
    private int type;
    private Long pId;
    @Setter
    private ReporterObject parent; // can be null
    @Setter
    private int n_a = 0;
}
```

What can be the problem then?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to flush Redis cache?

Comment: @NikitaKoksharov yeah, already tried that and it worked. Forgot to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @NikitaKoksharov said, flushing the cache does the trick.